# pintar célula através de um "ok" em outra célula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Bom dia, não sei se dará para entender meu raciocínio, mas vamos lá.....

Tenho uma célula que tem nomes exemplo: SABRINA (A1),preciso colocar OK na célula (B1), e após colocar o "OK", preciso que o nome fique na cor verde, para que eu saiba que conclui o cadastro da "Sabrina".